# install cvblobslib in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have been sitting two days now trying to setup visual studio 2010 with
cvblobs , I have installed opencv and it works perfectly but when I try adding cvblobs to the project it for some reason fails. I downloaded cvblobs and Generated it using Cmake but when I build it , I have these linked errors

error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\lib\Debug\cvblob.lib'   C:\cvblob\msvc\test\LINK    test_random
error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\lib\Debug\cvblob.lib'   C:\cvblob\msvc\test\LINK    test
error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\lib\Debug\cvblob.lib'   C:\cvblob\msvc\test\LINK    test_tracking

I am using Windows 7 64 bit...

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "adding cvblobslib to the project"? You should NOT add it to the OpenCV project. There is no need for Cmake for cvblobslib - it comes with a solution file. Also, your error says you are linking with cvblob.lib . It should be cvblobslib.lib

Comment: so sorry but I try install cvblobs not cvblobslib , so any solution for that ??